# Delta Live Table able to write to ADLS?

Tags: azure-databricks, delta-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2, delta-live-tables

I have a architectural requirement to have the data stored in ADLS under a medallion model, and are trying to achieve writing to ADLS using Delta Live Tables as a precursor to creating the Delta Table.

I've had had success using `CREATE TABLE {dlt_tbl_name} USING DELTA LOCATION {location_in_ADLS}` to create the Delta Table without Delta Live... however the goal is to use Delta live and I don't see how this method is supported in Delta Live

Anyone have a suggestion?  I'm guessing at this point that writing to ADLS isn't supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look into the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/workflows/delta-live-tables/delta-live-tables-python-ref#--create-table) then you can see that you can specify `path` parameter for the `@dlt.table` (for Python). And similarly, you can specify `LOCATION` parameter when using SQL ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/workflows/delta-live-tables/delta-live-tables-sql-ref#--create-table)).  You just need to make sure that you're provided all necessary Spark configuration parameters on the pipeline level (with [service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage#--access-azure-data-lake-storage-gen2-or-blob-storage-using-oauth-20-with-an-azure-service-principal) or [SAS token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage#access-azure-data-lake-storage-gen2-or-blob-storage-using-a-sas-token)).  Following code works just fine:

In Python:

```py
import dlt

@dlt.view
def input():
  return spark.range(10)

@dlt.table(
  path="abfss://test@<account>.dfs.core.windows.net/dlt/python"
)
def python():
  return dlt.read("input")
```

In SQL:

```sql
CREATE OR REFRESH LIVE TABLE sql 
LOCATION 'abfss://test@<account>.dfs.core.windows.net/dlt/sql'
AS SELECT * from LIVE.input
```