# How to configure path for Delta Live Table in cloud_files

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-live-tables

I am new to the Databricks Delta Live table. I have some small doubts and need your help to understand the concept behind it. I am unable to proceed without this.

I have a file in the Azure data lake container, and I know that I need to give the path under "cloud_files" so that delta live table can read files from this folder and show them. But my doubt is, if I give only the path, how do I mention the storage account name and container name? Also, do I need to provide an access key in order to read the data securely ?

I think I am missing something, I have gone through various articles and Youtube demo videos, and everywhere they just mention the path but do not tell me how to configure the path.

Please help me to understand this concept.

Thank You.

This is my code for the Delta Live table:

```
CREATE LIVE TABLE customers_raw
COMMENTS "This is raw table"
AS
SELECT *
FROM cloud_files("/raw_data/customers.csv", "csv")
```

Comment: hi @Atanu chatterjee, please provide sample code. what you tried.

Comment: You should mount object cloud storage first on DBFS /mnt folder (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dbfs/mounts). Then you can access it as you tried.

Comment: @partlov Mounts aren’t recommended anymore

Comment: @AlexOtt thanks, I didn't notice that. I see that it is deprecated on documentation page for Azure, but looking on AWS documentation I only see that it doesn't work with Unity Catalog, but can't find same deprecation message as on Azure doc.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/external-data/azure-storage#deprecated-patterns-for-storing-and-accessing-data-from-azure-databricks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify full URL for this folder, like, `abfss://<container>@<storage>.dfs.core.windows.net/raw_data/customers.csv`. Otherwise if you specify it `/raw_data/customers.csv` it will consider it as a folder on DBFS, and will fail.  Please note that in this case you will need to setup corresponding Spark properties so DLT can access data - you can find it in the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73532480/delta-live-table-able-to-write-to-adls/73540298#73540298).

Comment: One question regarding usability, if this is for example location where some delta table is stored and we not use mounting, but this approach, how access will work if people query this data through let's say SQL Warehouse? Will they be able to access data?

Comment: If `target` is specified in the DLT configuration, then DLT will create entries in metastore for tables pointing to that location, so people can simply work with these tables by their names. You just need to make sure that your SQL warehouses are configured correctly to access that storage location